# migrate in-app purchases to new app

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

My boss wants me to reboot an app we created, the first release did fairly poorly and now that the bugs are out and we have some new art: he wants to start over fresh with none of the bad reviews in the Market.

My problem: the app contained in-app purchases, and it seems unfair to the people who suffered through the initial bugs to make them buy things over again. If it was just a question of buying the new version I'd feel differently about it, but some people sunk $12 - $20 into add-ons for this app and I don't want to gyp them out of it since it's the exact same content in a better UI.

**Does anyone know of a way to migrate those purchases?**

It doesn't look like the device or Google user is listed in the viewable data from Google checkout, so I can't check against that.

I'm considering having them use their checkout phone number as a sort of 'coupon' in the app, since that is available from Google Checkout. It seems kind of inconvenient, though, and they may not remember off the top of their heads which phone number is their Checkout number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your old app so that the first time it is launched after update, the in-app-purchases are recorded and submitted to a database you create.

Comment: Well, it doesn't save the purchases of people who've already uninstalled the app, but I could point them to reinstall it to get their purchases back. Thanks for the idea.